# Getting battery information of a windows CE 5.0 device

Tags: compact-framework

Sir, I am developing an application for a device running WINDOWS CE 5.0. I want to know the battery/power information of the device. I am quit new in CE programming. Please make clear is there any difference between windows mobile programming and CE programming? I found MICROSOFT.WINDOWSMOBILE.STATUS namespace to work with. But when i include the reference, this namespace is not visible in the list. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [P/Invoke GetSystemPowerStatusEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.GetSystemPowerStatusEx).  An example is actually found in [this old MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446550.aspx).

Comment: Is there any other way to do the same witout using introp ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the P/Invoke GetSystemPowerStatusEx before and found it caused memory leaks when calling it frequently.  For reliable event driven battery status I'd go down the route of SystemState Events.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;
_batteryState = new SystemState(SystemProperty.PowerBatteryState) { ComparisonType = StatusComparisonType.AnyChange };
_batteryState.Changed += (o, e) => UpdateBatteryIcon();

private void UpdateBatteryIcon()
{
    var batteryLevel = SystemState.PowerBatteryStrength;
    var isOnCharge = IsOnCharge(SystemState.PowerBatteryState);
    _batteryWarning = batteryLevel == BatteryLevel.VeryLow && !isOnCharge;
    pictBattery.Image = GetBatteryIcon(batteryLevel, isOnCharge);
}
```

Comment: P/Invoking only causes leaks if you're doing it wrong.  System State is all well and good if the OS supports it, though I'm far from convinced it will work on his generic CE 5.0 device since the Microsoft.WindowsMobile.dll assembly won't be on the device.

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status dll is not available to add in the addlist when we develop application targetted to Windows CE device. Instead it is available if target is windows mobile.