# Check battery level in a Windows CE device

Tags: c#, windows-ce, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting battery information of a windows CE 5.0 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415622/getting-battery-information-of-a-windows-ce-5-0-device)

I need to check the battery level in a Windows CE device using c#. I need something like the Win32_Battery class but for Mobile Devices.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415622/getting-battery-information-of-a-windows-ce-5-0-device .. there are several other links on stackoverflow alone, did you look through them yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can p/invoke the `GetSystemPowerStatusEx` API to get battery status, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453172.aspx for the details.

A quick google search also yields a samples:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11736

and a tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446550.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help! the Microsoft sample helped me a lot